# Error cannot read properties of null (reading '_rawValidators')

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angular, asp.net-core

I'm kinda new to programming.. I recently got this error on my project and I can't figure out what it means exactly.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MIch.png)
when I press the submit button nothing happens.

this is my html:

```
<h1>
    <span *ngIf="pageMode == pageModeEnum.Create">Add Customer</span>
    <span *ngIf="pageMode == pageModeEnum.Edit">
      <span>Edit Customer </span>
      <span class="text-primary">{{ customer?.fullName }}</span>
    </span>
  </h1>
  <hr>
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <form [formGroup]="customerForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">
  
        <div class="">
          <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="w-100">
            <mat-label>First Name</mat-label>
            <input matInput formControlName="firstName" required>
            <mat-error *ngIf="customerForm.controls['firstName'].hasError('required')">First name is required</mat-error>
            <mat-error *ngIf="customerForm.controls['firstName'].hasError('minlength')
              ||
              customerForm.controls['firstName'].hasError('maxlength')">
              First name must be between 3 and 16 characters long.
            </mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
  
        <div class="">
          <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="w-100">
            <mat-label>Last Name</mat-label>
            <input matInput formControlName="lastName" required>
            <mat-error *ngIf="customerForm.controls['lastName'].hasError('required')">Last name is required</mat-error>
            <mat-error *ngIf="customerForm.controls['lastName'].hasError('minlength')
              ||
              customerForm.controls['lastName'].hasError('maxlength')">
              Last name must be between 3 and 16 characters long.
            </mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
  
        <div class="">
          <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="w-100">
            <mat-label>Phone</mat-label>
            <input matInput formControlName="phone" required>
            <mat-error>Phone number is required</mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>

        <div class="">
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="w-100">
              <mat-label>Email</mat-label>
              <input matInput formControlName="Email" required>
              <mat-error>Email is required</mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
          </div>
          <div class="">
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="w-100">
              <mat-label>Gender</mat-label>
              <mat-select formControlName="gender">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let gender of genderEnum | enumToArray " [value]="gender.index">
                  {{ gender.name }}
                </mat-option>
              </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>
          </div>
        <div>
          <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="w-100">
            <mat-label>Date of birth</mat-label>
            <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" formControlName="dob">
            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button class="me-2" [routerLink]="['/customers']" mat-stroked-button color="basic">Cancel</button>
          <button mat-flat-button color="primary" type="submit">
            <span *ngIf="pageMode == pageModeEnum.Create">Create</span>
            <span *ngIf="pageMode == pageModeEnum.Edit">Save</span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
  
    </div>`
  
  </div>
```

and this is the component:

```
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Gender } from 'app/enums/gender.enum';
import { PageMode } from 'app/enums/pageMode.enum';
import { Customer } from 'app/models/customer.model';
import { CustomerService } from 'app/services/customer.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-edit-customer',
  templateUrl: './add-edit-customer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-edit-customer.component.css'],

})
export class AddEditCustomerComponent implements OnInit {

  customerId?: number;
  customer?: Customer;
  customerForm!: FormGroup;
  genderEnum = Gender;
  pageMode: PageMode = PageMode.Create;
  pageModeEnum = PageMode;

  constructor(
    private customerSvc: CustomerService,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.setCustomerId();
    this.setPageMode();

    this.buildForm();

    if (this.pageMode == PageMode.Edit) {

      this.loadCustomer();
    }
  }

  submitForm() {

    if (this.customerForm.valid) {

      if (this.pageMode == PageMode.Create) {

        this.customerSvc.createCustomer(this.customerForm.value).subscribe({
          next: (customerFromApi) => {
            this.router.navigate(['/customers']);
          },
          error: (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            console.log(error);
          }
        });
      }
      else {

        this.customerSvc.editCustomer(this.customerId!, this.customerForm.value).subscribe({
          next: () => {
            this.router.navigate(['/customers']);
          },
          error: (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            console.log(error);
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }

  //#region Private Methods

  private buildForm() {

    this.customerForm = this.fb.group({
      id: [0],
      firstName: ['', Validators.compose(
        [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(16)]
      )],
      lastName: ['', Validators.compose(
        [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(16)]
      )],
      gender: ['', Validators.required],
      email: ['', Validators.required],
      dob: ['', Validators.required],
      phone: []
    });
  }

  private setCustomerId(): void {

    this.customerId = Number(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));
  }

  private setPageMode(): void {

    if (this.customerId) {

      this.pageMode = PageMode.Edit
    }
  }

  private loadCustomer() {

    this.customerSvc.getCustomer(this.customerId!).subscribe({
      next: (customerFromApi : Customer) => {
        this.customer = customerFromApi;
        this.patchForm(customerFromApi);
      },
      error: (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
  }

  private patchForm(customerFromApi: Customer) {

    this.customerForm.patchValue({
      id: customerFromApi.id,
      firstName: customerFromApi.firstName,
      lastName: customerFromApi.lastName,
      gender: customerFromApi.gender,
      email: customerFromApi.email,
      dob: customerFromApi.dob,
      phone: customerFromApi.phone
    });
  }

  //#endregion

}
```

I searched everywhere but couldn't find answers explaining exactly what was happening.

Comment: `formControlName="Email"` here email should be lowercase, as in your model

Comment: Ensure that the names you use in the formControlName directives in your HTML template match the names you've defined in your reactive form (customerForm). Any mismatch can lead to this error.

Comment: I fixed the names but I still have that error